# does not display the result (Java)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, glassfish, jakarta-ee

Hello trying to figure out the Jsf (primefaces) and little that goes viz. Compiled war archive in maven try to run through the Glassfish, the server starts but in the beginning writing    "Artifact qwe-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available."  But in the late writes "Artifact qwe-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait... Artifact is deployed successfully." It seems like everything is normal, then opened my page in the browser is empty although in my index.xhtm and my pom.xml and web.xml [link pastebin](http://pastebin.com/H75C0ygp)
and should be a button with styles that are connected in primefaces  tell me if I'm doing something wrong? 
here's a screenshot of the result in the browser. [link1](http://f-picture.net/lfp/s48.radikal.ru/i119/1410/b8/c086f5001deb.png/htm)

Comment: At the least you're missing h:head and h:body

Comment: I think of nothing depends on it, and the button should be in any case

Answer (score 0):

`<p:button outcome="productDetail" value="Bookmark" icon="ui-icon-star">` targets you to the productDetail page. If you do not have productDetail.xhtml page at the currect path, the index.xhtml page cannot resolve NavigationCase for outcome. Thus, Create page productDetail.xhtml and put into the same directory of index.xhtml.

In addition, You should use JSF Standard tags(h:head, h:body).

Comment: @Deres why you do not interest my answer. If my answer cannot help you, you should comment. I want to know. If it not work, I will delete my post.